# A wealthy person

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a phrase that will mean an affluent people. This phrase should contain a word that means "the sound of coin dropping".
Is there any phrase like this?

Comment: I imagine a coin dropping would be silent, but a coin hitting the ground could make various sounds depending on what it's made of.  *Plink* comes to mind.

Comment: Also, no, I can't think of any idiomatic phrase meaning "affluent people" that contains onomatopoeia for a coin striking a hard surface.

Comment: Especially, rich people usually don't like to drop their coins.

Comment: The most common English term for a rich person that references coins is ***moneybags***, but apart from one well-known poetic reference to [clinking moneybags](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22clinking+moneybags%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), sound is not usually associated with that term.

Comment: Just as a point of reference *an affluent people* would refer to a rich nation as a whole, while a *wealthy person* refers to an individual.

Comment: There's nothing that says you can't make up your own phrase.  Going off @jwpat7's answer you might say, "George? Yeah, his *pockets always jingle*, I think."

Comment: You might even say, "He drops dimes like a Rockefeller"

Comment: @Jim, in my experience, "drop a dime [on somebody]" is more often used as an idiom meaning to inform law enforcement of a criminal activity.

Comment: @ThePhoton- Yeah, I thought about that too.  in fact for a bit of fun you might express the idea that this guy spends his money freely, you might say, "This guy drops dimes quicker than a police informer."

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any English idiom with the sound of a coin dropping, but there is a phrase that says *money to burn*. I'd usually hear it said in a context like this one:

> Wow, I can't believe that Fred spent more than $60,000 on his new car!
>
> Yeah, that guy has **money to burn**.

The idiom means that the guy has ***so*** much money, he could just burn some of it, which seems similar in some ways to the notion of coins dropping.

Come to think of it, I've also heard the expression *money falling out of his pockets*, such as in this book excerpt:

> But suddenly, at forty-nine, with **money falling out of his pockets**, respected by his peers, and a thriving empire, he had found what was missing in his life – he'd fallen in love.
> <sub>(from *Spy With The Silver Lining* by Wendy Rosnau)</sub>

Again, no noises are given in that idiom; however, it still seems close to what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

An entry under *Jingle* in OED1 (1901; vol. 5 part 2, page 584) lists the term *jingle-boy* in reference to  “a man who has plenty of money in his pockets”:

> 1. *attrib.* and *Comb.* (see also senses 4 and 5), as
>      *jingle-bell*, etc. (see quots.) ; jingle-boy (*slang*),
>      a coin, *spec.* a sovereign ; also, a man who has
>      plenty of money in his pockets.

However, the term isn't frequently used.

Answer (score 0):

I found one word (onomatopoeia) for the sound of coin, ***clink***. It's not quite dropping, but must sound nice for those who seek wealthiness.

> The first storehouse of my treasure was a well-purse. I loathed its useless emptiness. I desired it be round and full, **clinking with the sound of gold**. Therefore, I sought every remedy for a lean purse. I found seven.
>   <sub>--*The Richest Man in Babylon*, by George S. Clason</sub>

Also, another similar sound is ***clank***.